# Want to give different ID to each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add HTML tag into the values. 
http://jsfiddle.net/iamakshay04/seyzta8c/1/

Above is the fiddle. When checkbox is clicked, the values are printed, I want to print each value as a different html element. `<p>1</p> <p>2</p> <p>3</p>`

```js
$('.ads_Checkbox').click(function() {
    var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
    }).get();
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sel;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id="ad_Checkbox1" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox2" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox3" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox4" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="button" id="save_value" name="save_value" value="Save" />

<p id="demo">

</p>
```

Comment: heading and question description does not match. Heading says different id and description says different html elements as values. Please clear the question.

Comment: GO with description, ignore the heading :( -_- deadline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show values as different elements then try below where you can add paragraphs at the time of reading the values.

```js
$('.ads_Checkbox').click(function() {
    var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return "<p>"+ $(el).val() + "</p>";
    }).get();
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sel;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id="ad_Checkbox1" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox2" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox3" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox4" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="button" id="save_value" name="save_value" value="Save" />

<p id="demo">

</p>
```

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the different elements:-

```js
$('.ads_Checkbox').change(function() {
    var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $('<p></p>').html($(el).val());
    }).get();
    
    $("#demo").html(sel);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id="ad_Checkbox1" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox2" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox3" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input  id="ad_Checkbox4" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="button" id="save_value" name="save_value" value="Save" />

<p id="demo">

</p>
```